# Name for assuming a 50-50 split

Tags: bayesian

is there a term or principal for assuming a 50-50 split for complimentary events (they can’t both be true but one has to be true) when you have no data for the actual split/proportion.

Sorry this is really simple but I'm new to Stats!

Comment: You might be hunting for Laplace's *Principle of Insufficient Reason.*  It does not apply to complementary events, but many people have mistakenly supposed it does, leading to all kinds of contradictions, paradoxes, and errors.

Comment: Also look into noninformative (or reference) priors